# Enabling/Disabling Group Policy On-Demand

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I am currently working at a school that needs some Group Policy enforcements, which have been set up successfully.

However, the teachers want to be able to enable/disable the "Run only specified Windows applications" policy at will. Is there a way to do this?

Preferably, the teachers should be able to do this directly from the student account (with UAC). How should I set this up?

---

I am running Windows 7 Professional, non-domain.

Comment: Why don't you just use run as admin the have teachers enter their password because there is no way to do what you want with a student account which wouldn't make said policy meaningless

Comment: Exactly what sort of policy is *Run only specified Windows applications*?  Is it an [AppLocker](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5211.how-to-configure-applocker-group-policy-to-prevent-software-from-running.aspx) policy?